# variables in element definition in jquery callback function

Tags: jquery

new to jquery, can't find a solution.

Problem:
in a callback function, I want 2 elements to fade out. They are both "a" tags, with different ids: one ID is the incoming "data", and that works fine, the other is "data" with the word "plus" appended (this is the one that does NOT fade). 
This is the code I have, thus far:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function callback(data, status)
    {
      $('a[id = ' + data + ']').fadeOut(1000, function() {
      $('a[id = ' + data + ' plus]').fadeOut(1000);
      });  
    }
</script>
```

Can anybody help? much appreciated!

Comment: Remove the space between the **id** like `$('a[id = "' + data + 'plus"]')`

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function callback(data, status)
{
  $('#' + data).fadeOut(1000, function() {
    $('#' + data + 'plus').fadeOut(1000);
  });  
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the space in the selector.

```
function callback(data, status)
    {
      $('a[id = ' + data + ']').fadeOut(1000, function() {
      $('a[id = ' + data + 'plus]').fadeOut(1000); //space removed
      });  
    }

callback("test");
```

**Js Fiddle** http://jsfiddle.net/wXLcC/

Comment: @user2747129 Are you sure jQuery is included? Are you placing your code within document.ready()?

Comment: the ajax itself is within document.ready, the callback is not. Should it be? thank you

Comment: the fiddle works; the script is the same on the page but does not work. Could there be some kind of time-out issue? the first a tag fades, the second not. Any ideas? thank you